# Can you make black light?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Is it possible to create blackness using a bulb??

If not, how do they make the colour  "Black" in TVs and mobilephone screens?

Do they make use of some destructive interference or something ?

Comment: Re, "how do they make the colour "Black" in TVs...?"  If you look at a modern TV screen when it's turned off, it looks black.  They make pixels look "black" by turning them off.  That's the simple part.  The hard part is getting pixels to look black when turned off and still be reasonably bright when it's turned on.  Engineers have been trying to improve the "blackness" of video displays (a.k.a., "improve the _contrast ratio_") for as video displays have existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black light is not possible. In current LCD technology, the light from the screen is actually a panel of white light behind the pixels called the back light. The light shines through the colored pixels which filter out light to give what ever color you see. The black in this case is a total blockout of the back light for those pixels that are black.

In OLED technology, the pixels themselves produce light and black in that case is an off state of the pixel.